# File Copying With C#. Filetype

Tags: c#

I want to copy a file to a directory with this app. The only problem is that it needs to be the same file type as it was in the directory it came from. In this code i have to put the file type behind the name. When I copy the file to the 2nd directory, It automatically becomes an .txt. I want the same extension as it had in the first directory. How do I do this? 
Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Transfer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        File.Copy(@""+textBox1.Text, @""+textBox2.Text+"/"+ textBox3.Text);
        label2.Text = "File Transfer Succeeded";
    }

    private void Filesource_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult resDialog = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (resDialog.ToString() == "OK")
        {
            textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void Target_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult resDialog = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (resDialog.ToString() == "OK")
        {
            textBox2.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: See [FileInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx).

Comment: Also, instead of concatenating strings as you are, use `Path.Combine(textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text)`.

Comment: Just interesting - what the benefit of doing this `@""+textBox1.Text`?

Comment: What is the problem in that? And by "file type", do you mean "file extension"? Have you looked at [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx)?

Comment: @""+textBox1.Text is the path of the file. So what is in textBox1 will be the path for the file.

Comment: @ Nolonar both work i think

Comment: @ CodeCaster I mean that when i want to transfer a Word document that it needs to stay a Word Document. In my application i can change the type. I HAVE to type the file. Which i dont want to.

Comment: @loko Ah yes, I see it's a forward slash. By the way, what lazyberezovsky meant, is why you do `@""+textBox1.Text` instead of simply `textBox1.Text`

Comment: Ow thanks :D But can anyone help with the question i asked? xd

Comment: And yes i mean file extension @CodeCaster how can i make sure they have the same file extension when i copy?

Comment: Your code is not obvious... You should have decent button / variable names for us to be able to figure out what you want to do.

Comment: My guess is that the solution to your problem somewhere will include a call somewhat similar to this : `Path.GetExtension(originalFileName)`

Comment: DislogResult is an enumeration and you can use it as "if(resDialog == DialogResult.OK)" which is more efficient as ToString and less errorprone.

Comment: @ mortb i editted my question. + Where should i put that code?

Comment: @loko: If your problem is solved you should mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you want to do this:

```
private void Transfer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        File.Copy(textBox1.Text, Path.Combine(textBox2.Text, Path.ChangeExtension(textBox3.Text, Path.GetExtension(textBox1.Text)));
        label2.Text = "File Transfer Succeeded";
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
string sourcePath = @"c:\myDocument.docx";
            string targetPath = @"c:\xyzHello.crazyextension";
            string sourceExtension = Path.GetExtension(sourcePath);
            if (sourceExtension != Path.GetExtension(targetPath))
                targetPath = Path.ChangeExtension(targetPath, sourceExtension);
            File.Copy(sourcePath, targetPath);
```